# I made an error when using metawrap to binning

Tags: sequence, binning, samtools

my code

```
metawrap binning -o bin_out -t 24 -m 200 -a all_contig/all_merge.fasta --metabat2 --maxbin2 --concoct all_fastq/*fastq
```

Error reported as follows

```
sorting the SRR10492802 alignment file
[bam_sort_core] merging from 24 files and 24 in-memory blocks...
[E::sam_hdr_sanitise] Malformed SAM header at line 2
samtools sort: failed to read header from "bin_out/work_files/tmp-samtools.0000.bam"
somthing  went wrong with sortin the alignments
Exiging
```

Request answers for me how to solve the problem. Thank you very much.

Add a supplement, there is the header of sam file.

```
samtools view -H SRR10492802.sam|head -10
@SQ SN:k141_390421 LN:651
@SQ SN:k141_39985 LN:538
@SQ SN:k141_334641 LN:682
@SQ SN:k141_55776 LN:692
@SQ SN:k141_39781 LN:589
@SQ SN:k141_450722 LN:843
@SQ SN:k141_563831 LN:707
@SQ SN:k141_350441 LN:651
@SQ SN:k141_270821 LN:1427
@SQ SN:k141_111552 LN:779
```